# fadeTo two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an image on my site to opacity 0.5 and then i want to "pop out" on this image a word with opacity equal to 1. The problem is that when i set image on whatever speed it starts to queue all functions as many times as i enter/leave image with my cursor.

1. the word is loading faster (immadietly) than image with 'slow' and
   the word doesn't change opacity to 1, cus it's loosing opacity with
   image (which is set to 0.5)
2. How to make "word" to load later than image?
3. How to make function not repeatable whenever I'm moving my cursor through image (like 10x/sec) so it won't queue everything and
   continue to fadeTo until everything is done?
4. (the most important) How to make word to not inherit opacity from image?

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#classic').mouseenter(function(){
           $('#classic').fadeTo('slow', 0.25)
       {
           $('#classic').append("Classic");
           $("Classic").fadeTo('slow', 1);
       };
       });

       $('#classic').mouseleave(function(){
           $('#classic').fadeTo('slow', 1);
           {
               $('#classic').empty();
           };
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: can you have it on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3dytbr3m/

inside borders are images
|||
done only for 1 to see the effects, since i didn't receive effects i wanted i didn't copy/paste code to others

Comment: You have some extra curly braces that do not make sense. They are causing syntax errors along with some missing semi-colons. Have you checked your console for these errors and eliminated them?

Comment: mmm, i don't understand exactly what do you mean by "your console". You mean that i should use console.log? Because I'm suing Notepad++ and this program doesn't show any syntax errors (or am i supposed to tick option somewhere to make notepad show this errors?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that either (a) the element that has `id="classic"` is not an `img`--because `img`es should not have children--or (b) you are adding the text after the `img` and not appending it to it.  I'm going to assume that there's a div with `id="classic"` which has an `img` child:

1) You have it almost right.  To make the word fade in after the image has faded out you need to use a callback function.  The syntax for this is:

```
$('#classic').fadeTo('slow', 0.25, function() {
    // now the fading is done!
});
```

And not

```
$('#classic').fadeTo('slow', 0.25)
{
    ....
}
```

You'll also probably want to add `opacity: 0` for an initial value on the text that you add to the DOM so you can then fade it in.

2) jQuery has a function just for this called `.stop()`.  Call this function whenever you need to stop animations from queuing up.  So change the above to:

```
$('#classic').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.25, function() {
    // now the fading is done!
});
```

3) In CSS all elements inherit opacity from their parent.  The easiest fix for this is simply to make the added element a sibling (or any other DOM element) of the transparent element and not a child.  Then use negative relative positioning to stick it over the transparent element.  So, assuming this structure:

```
<div id="classic">
    <img src="myPicture" />
</div>
```

you'd use this jQuery:

```
$('#classic img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.25, function() {
    $('#classic').append("<span>Classic</span>");
    $("#classic span").fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

Make only the image fade out and in, so its siblings are unaffected.  And in CSS:

```
#classic span {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0; /* make it 0 initially so we can fade it in */
    position: relative;
    top: -48px; /* or whatever value */
    left: -88px; /* or whatever value */
}
```

So here's the combined jQuery:

```
$('#classic').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#classic img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.25, function() {
        $('#classic').append("<span>Classic</span>");
        $("#classic span").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});

$('#classic').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#classic img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
        $('#classic span').remove();
    });
});
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8f4s4gk/).  Hope this helps!

Comment: This is such a perfect answer, especially the part where you explain everything! Thank you very much!

Comment: @nehel You're welcome.  Sorry I did not see that you'd posted a fiddle with your actual code.  Here's a fiddle with your code utilizing some of what I posted: http://jsfiddle.net/3dytbr3m/2/

Comment: Just noticed that you replied! Thanks for reply and I've managed to make it as you've shown above before you replied! Although I have one more question. How can i make everything to happen at once? I mean, image fade out to 0.5 and fade in "classic" to 1 when there is .mouseenter and the same for .mouseleave with fade in img to opacity 1 and "classic" fade out to 0? (Already editted a bit the "classic" to be removed after fading out in both ways, firstly "classic" dissapeaing then img is fading in and 2nd first img fading in / classic fading out)
http://jsfiddle.net/3dytbr3m/3/

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3dytbr3m/1/

You should use classes on your buttons. Classes are identifiers that can be applied on multiple elements. That way you don't have to use double code.

I also use `$(this)` which means that you are targeting the element that has the mouse over.

Comment: Ah... I actually know this, thats why i've put all divs into class "option", but i wanted to check on single button to see the effects ^^ But thanks for showing other way to apply this effects. Just started my adventure with jQuery 2 days ago and i don't mind adding new options to my new jQuery drawer in brain!

Comment: Using `$(this)` will save you a lot of headaches. ;-)

Comment: So basically $(this) will always be for the one specific function above it i guess?

Comment: Yes, it returns the element on which the method is invoked. You can read more about it here: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Comment: Roger that! Thanks for every tip! I really appreciate it.